# Get mean of values over a certain age

Tags: python, aggregate-functions, data-analysis

I'm trying to answer this question:

What was the average bmi recorded for patients above 50 years old?

This is what I tried:

```
average_bmi_df = insurance_df.bmi.mean()
average_bmi_df
```

However this only gives me the bmi of all ages (30.665470852017993), I'm just trying to get **over 50**.

Comment: Use `.loc` to filter for rows and columns. Then, do the mean: `average_bmi_df = insurance_df.loc[insurance_df['age'] > 50, ['bmi']].mean()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. I guess this code help you

```
average_bmi_df = insurance_df.bmi[insurance_df['age'] > 50].mean()
```